# Error using both lookahead and look behind regex

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I am having a problem using the following regex. It works fine in regexr and rubular but it gives me an error when running it on node.js. I am fairly new to using regex and i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong. It will work if I knock off the `(?<= )` so I presume that is the problem.

I'm trying to match 'is' with a leading and trailing space using `/(?<= )is(?= )|==/g`

Example with test words:
http://regexr.com?33781

Node error output

```
 temp = temp.replace(/(?<= )is(?= )|==/g, '===');
^
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(?<= )is(?= )|==/: Invalid group
at new RegExp (unknown source)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

JavaScript regex does not support lookbehind at all.

Sources:

- http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#limitbehindand
- http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

However, [you *can* fake it in some cases](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript).

Answer (score 2):

Quite simply, this is because JavaScript regular expressions have no support for lookbehinds:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html

Lookbehind is not supported at all. Lookahead is fully supported.