# React Native regex causes a crash on iOS 11.2

Tags: react-native

**Description**

The app crashes only on iOS 11.2 giving me `unhandled JS Exception: Invalid regular expression: unrecognized character after (?`  while not in debug mode.
I've tested the same code on iOS 13 and it works fine. I eventually figured out which regex were causing the problem and I found out that all regex of this type   `(?<value>\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})` were causing the crash they are stored as value of a Javascript Object in a separate .js file. I'm asking for a solution that doesn't require changing all the regex.

I don't understand why the behaviour on iOS 13 is different from iOS 11.2.

Also I found a similar issue with lookbehind regex at this link [Crash if not in debug on android and iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54275266/crash-if-not-in-debug-on-android-and-ios).

**What I've already tried**

- First thing first I tried to update React Native to the latest
  version 0.61.5, but it didn't solve my issue
- I've tried to replicate the same issue in a fresh new project and it didn't crash
- Tried to remove all the regex, this worked, but the regex are part of a big and important functionality of the app

**Environment**

```
System:
    OS: macOS 10.15.2
    CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8559U CPU @ 2.70GHz
    Memory: 461.18 MB / 16.00 GB
  Binaries:
    Node: 13.3.0 - /usr/local/Cellar/node/13.3.0/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.19.2 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
    npm: 6.13.4 - /usr/local/bin/npm
    Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: iOS 13.2, DriverKit 19.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.2, watchOS 6.1
    Android SDK:
      API Levels: 28, 29
      Build Tools: 28.0.3, 29.0.2
      System Images: android-29 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-29 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 3.5 AI-191.8026.42.35.5977832
    Xcode: 11.3/11C29 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  npmPackages:
    react: 16.8.6 => 16.8.6 
    react-native: ^0.60.5 => 0.60.5 
  npmGlobalPackages:
    react-native-cli: 2.0.1
```

**Screenshots**

[image: iPhone 6s simulator running iOS 11.2]

**Thanks for reading**

Answer (score 3):

What i would suggest is if you see that its not working on some specific ios version , check for the ios version and if its ios 13 and above use that regex or try some other regex which works in 11.2.

You can check the iosVersion by

```
    import {Platform} from 'react-native';

    const majorVersionIOS = parseInt(Platform.Version, 10);
    if (majorVersionIOS <= 13) {
      console.log('YOu need some other regex');
    } else {
console.log('YOu can use same regex');
}
```

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I was hoping to find a way to avoid substituting all the regex, what still concerns me is that the same regex is working perfectly fine on a fresh new project

Answer (score 1):

We ended up removing all the regexes from the app, and implemented them in the backend.