# Need alternative solution for regex in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, react-native, webview

I am trying to wrap each word in HTML string with a span tag. The following regex is working but I am getting error sometimes invalid regular expressions in react native ios and android both and it may be due to negative look behind can anyone help to replace this regex?

```
htmlStr.replace(/(?<!(<\/?[^>]*|&[^;]*))([^\s<]+)/g, ‘$1<span class="word">$2</span>‘)
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript Regex does not support lookbehind, [which is a well-documented fact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13993793/error-using-both-lookahead-and-look-behind-regex?answertab=votes#tab-top) to the point you've answered your own question. JavaScript has plenty of ways to match a substring within a string, so I'd definitely start with that instead of overengineering a regex grab.